# Adding images in campaign template in mailchimp using mailchimp api

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

How can i add images to my template while creating campaign content.?

my template div is like :

```
<div mc:edit="header_image"></div>

And my content body is like :
var contentbody = {
        'template' :{
            'id':215313,
            'sections':{
                'header_date': 'March 10-17th, 2017',
                'header_title': 'Weekly NewsLetter',
                'community_name': 'My Community',
                'header_image': '<img src="./MyPic.png"/>'
            }
        }
    };
```

But the image is not getting rendered.

Comment: Do you get anything on your console?

Comment: Sorry. I am new to this. Where is the console? I am logging the response of the request for creating campaign content. I am able to send the campaign mail. But in that the images are missing. How the image resources getting added to the content?